# Code Signing J2ME Application

Tags: java, java-me, code-signing

I have my application written in j2me , written for specific mobile phone i.e. Nokia 2690

My requirement is to perform File IO operation without asking user permission.
I mean i want to obtain trusted domain [or any under which this requirement belongs]

I am complete beginner.
Please provide me help .
Also provide me the Authority from which i should purchase certificate

Answer (score 0):

You find all the informations needed on [javaverified.com](http://javaverified.com/). It is quite a complex and costly process I might add.